# second command in a batch for loop

Tags: batch-file, for-loop

I want to write a code in batch like the following:

```
for %%a in (%list%) do (
    command1
    command2
    command3
    command4
    .
    .  
    .
)
```

The first command for the first element of the list is executed correctly. But in command2 there are errors. In the cmd-window I can see what happend. And in the command isn't changed the %%a to the value. There is a "%a" instead of the value. In my code there is "%%a" exactly like in command1.

What is the mistake here? How can I execute more than one command in a batch-for-loop?

complete script:

```
set machines=pc1 pc2 pc3 pc4 
set source1="\\%%a\c$\Data1"
set source2="\\%%a\c$\Data2"
set dest1="\\server\share\%%a\data1\%date%
set dest2="\\server\share\%%a\data2\%date%
set log1=\\server\share\log\log_%date%_data1.txt
set log2=\\server\share\log\log_%date%_data2.txt
set mail="success"
set errormail="error"
set betreff="successmail"
set errorbetreff="errormail"
set empf="dummy@test.com" 
set blat="pathtoblat\blat.exe"
set error=0

for %%a in (%machines%) do (

    %windir%\system32\robocopy.exe %source1% %dest1% /e /COPYALL /log:%log1%

    if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 16 echo ***FATAL ERROR*** & goto error
    ... different errorlevels
    if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 echo No Change & goto next



    :error
    set error=1



    :next
    %windir%\system32\robocopy.exe %source2% %dest2% /e /COPYALL /log:%log2%

    if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 16 echo ***FATAL ERROR*** & goto errormail
    ... different errorlevels
    if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 echo No Change



    if error==1 goto errormail
    goto mail



    :errormail
    %blat% -to %empf% -f %COMPUTERNAME%@test.com -server 172.y.y.y -s %errorbetreff% -body %errormail% -attacht %log1%,%log2%
    goto loeschen

    :mail
    %blat% -to %empf% -f %COMPUTERNAME%@test.com -server 172.y.y.y -s %betreff% -body %mail%

    :loeschen
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion
    pushd "\\server\share\backup\%COMPUTERNAME%\data1" && (
        for /f "skip=2 delims=" %%a in (
            'dir /b /ad /tc /o-d'
        ) do rmdir /s /q "%%~fa"
        popd
    )

    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion
    pushd "\\server\share\backup\%COMPUTERNAME%\data2" && (
        for /f "skip=2 delims=" %%a in (
            'dir /b /ad /tc /o-d'
        ) do rmdir /s /q "%%~fa"
        popd
    )

    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion
    pushd "\\server\share\log" && (
        for /f "skip=4 delims=" %%a in (
            'dir /b /a-d /tc /o-d'
        ) do del /q "%%~fa"
        popd
    )
)
```

Thanks

Comment: `%%a` in a file will always  look like `%a` in the command prompt , because this is how scripts are parsed.Rather the problem is in your command.

Comment: But it's exactly the same command. It's a robocopy job from one pc (with two folders) to the server. the list is the list of machines, that i want to backup. first command \\pc1\folder1 is backuped. in the second command it fails and in the window is written \\%a\folder2 instad of \\pc1\folder2 ..

Comment: better post whole your code.It's hard to see what could be the issue like that.(you can set some dummy paths if the ones you use are confidential)

Comment: could be a special symbol in your list like bracket quote ...

Comment: complete script added

Comment: one problem i see is that you use %%a as variable in the inner for loops too, which is not a good idea.

Comment: I don't have time for a full answer at the moment. But you cannot use GOTO within a FOR loop or IF block. But you can use CALL. Also, you must use delayed expansion when expanding a variable within same block that sets the variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's clear now where the error comes from.`GOTO` breaks the `FOR` context and `%%a`does not exist anymore . Rewrite the batch using subroutines and `CALL` instead of `GOTO`

Comment: But there are still `goto :eof` at the end of the subroutines?!

Comment: okay, I used exit /b and the last `goto :eof` is set behind the for loop. So it works perfectly. THANK YOU!