# Batch Script for loop with more than one statement

Tags: batch-file

Right now I need to loop through the content of a file,

This loop works fine and prints the content of the file

```
for /F %%x in (Test.txt) do @echo %%x
```

However because later on I want to do something else with the content I need to have more than one statement in this loop therefor I would like to use the following syntax:

```
for /F in (Test.txt) do 
some more statements
done
```

Unfortunately the latter does not work? How do I get a for loop to execute multiple commands?

Comment: This syntax is not `bash`. Looks more like `batch` to me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [second command in a batch for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26013750/second-command-in-a-batch-for-loop)

Comment: @bishop The tagged link is actually not a possible duplicate. It's related to a `goto` statement inside a codeblock which then exits the loop, where this question is an attempt to run multiple commands for a single `for` statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To run multiple commands for a single loop, you need to enclose the commands in a parenthesised code block:

```
for /F %%I in (Test.txt) do (
   echo %%i
   echo "%%i"
   echo etc
)
```

Be careful however as `set`ting and using variables inside of a loop may require `delayedexpansion`

See from `cmd.exe` help for:

```
for /?
setlocal /?
set /?
```